# What does the idiom "come together" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

Here is a sentence from a schedule planner app:

> This app lets you see how a plan comes together.

I am not sure how the [lexical meanings](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-together) of the idiom "come together" fit here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Come together" can also mean that something is developing or working out as you want it to. In this case, the app is letting you see how the plan gets set up and working effectively.

> **3** : to begin to work or proceed in the desired way
>   // The project started slowly, but everything is finally starting to *come together* now.

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20together).

Comment: I added the actual quotation from the dictionary to your answer, so it will continue to exist even if the link no longer does. (I also cleaned up the formatting of the link.) Feel free to change this presentation if you'd like it to look different.